# Why is EC2 taking so long to execute these SQLite queries?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, sqlite

I'm working on a script that a teammate of mine used to build an SQLite3 database locally on his machine. I made some modifications so that we can use it in our Django application to update the database with new data uploaded by the user. The application allows the user to upload a zip file containing multiple well-formatted csv files and adds the information from the csv's to the database. These are the relevant parts of the code:

**update_db.py**

```
import glob, sqlite3, pandas, timeit, re

def upload_files(csv_files):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/my_db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    added_tables = []

    for row in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
            table_name = re.sub(r'\W+', '', str(row))
            added_tables.append(table_name)

    for csv_filename in csv_files.namelist():
        if csv_filename.endswith('.csv'):
            csv_file = csv_files.open(csv_filename)

            # extract team name from csv_file string, remove whitespace
            table_name = csv_filename.rsplit('/',2)[1]
            table_name = re.sub('[^\w+]', '', table_name)


            try:
                df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, error_bad_lines=False)
                df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

                if table_name not in added_tables:
                    # add necessary columns

                    c.execute('alter table ' + str(table_name) + ' add team_BASEDOWN integer;')
                    c.execute('alter table ' + str(table_name) + ' add team_FIELDPOSITION integer;')
                    c.execute('alter table ' + str(table_name) + ' add team_HEADCOACH text;')
                    c.execute('alter table ' + str(table_name) + ' add team_OFFCOOR text;')
                    c.execute('alter table ' + str(table_name) + ' add team_DEFFCOOR text;')
                    added_tables.append(table_name)

                # set basedown
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 0 where pff_DOWN = 1 or (pff_DOWN = 2 and pff_DISTANCE <= 6);')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 1 where pff_DOWN = 2 and pff_DISTANCE >= 7;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 2 where pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE <= 2;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 3 where pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE = 3;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 4 where pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE >= 4 and pff_DISTANCE <= 6;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 5 where pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE >= 7;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_BASEDOWN = 6 where pff_DOWN = 4;')

                # set fieldposition
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_FIELDPOSITION = 0 where pff_FIELDPOSITION <= -1 and pff_FIELDPOSITION >= -10;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_FIELDPOSITION = 1 where pff_FIELDPOSITION <= -11 or (pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 20 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 50);')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_FIELDPOSITION = 2 where pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 12 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 20;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_FIELDPOSITION = 3 where pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 6 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 11;')
                c.execute('update ' + str(table_name) + ' set team_FIELDPOSITION = 4 where pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 5;')

            except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError as ex:
                print(str(csv_file) + ' was empty; continuing...')
                continue;

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from webapp.update_db import upload_files
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import zipfile

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        if str(myfile.name).endswith('.zip'):
            unzipped = zipfile.ZipFile(myfile)
            upload_files(unzipped)
    return render(request, 'webapp/upload.html')
```

My problem is that when I submit the zip, the upload takes a ridiculously long time to process (it took roughly 12 hours when dealing with a 160MB zip file). I feel like the SQL queries could be more efficient but he said that when he ran it locally it only took about 45 minutes to build the whole database (which is much larger than what we are expecting as "updates") so I'm wondering if there's something weird going on with the EC2 instance on which the application is running. I checked the CPU utilization on the instance and it shows a consistent average of 20% during the time that the update script was running (no noteworthy spikes or valleys either). I'm not sure what would have changed between running the instance locally vs running it on EC2 so any suggestions on modifications to the instance or to the script that would improve performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What instance type are you running this on? There is the chance that the instance has less capacity than your teammates.

Comment: I can't explain why it's quicker for your friend, but running all those alter table queries is never going to be efficient and will get less so as your database grows. I can't understand why you are doing this, but there are certainly better ways of doing whatever it is you want to achieve.

Comment: There's also the matter of all of these columns being apparently unindexed.  Add some benchmarking between each query to see what you can learn about which parts are slow... and, of course, check the CloudWatch metrics on your EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

You can update both columns for all cases with a single command:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET team_BASEDOWN = CASE
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 1 or (pff_DOWN = 2 and pff_DISTANCE <= 6) THEN 0
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 2 and pff_DISTANCE >= 7 THEN 1
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE <= 2 THEN 2
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE = 3 THEN 3
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE >= 4 and pff_DISTANCE <= 6 THEN 4
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 3 and pff_DISTANCE >= 7 THEN 5
                    WHEN pff_DOWN = 4 THEN 6
                    ELSE team_BASEDOWN
                    END,
    team_FIELDPOSITION = CASE
                         WHEN pff_FIELDPOSITION <= -1 and pff_FIELDPOSITION >= -10 THEN 0
                         WHEN pff_FIELDPOSITION <= -11 or (pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 20 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 50) THEN 1
                         WHEN pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 12 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 20 THEN 2
                         WHEN pff_FIELDPOSITION >= 6 and pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 11 THEN 3
                         WHEN pff_FIELDPOSITION <= 5 THEN 4
                         ELSE team_FIELDPOSITION
                         END;
```